# C# TCP socket server: broadcast received messages to all connected clients

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I have a ***AsyncSocketServer*** class which manages a TCP socket server. This one receives messages asynchronously from the its users, where each "user session" is managed in a separated thread and raises an event called ***NewData*** when a new message arrives

```
while ((bytesRead = await state.workSocket.ReceiveTask (state.buffer)) > 0)
{
        string message = state.sb.Append (Encoding.UTF8.GetString (state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));           

        var targetEvent = NewData;

        if (targetEvent != null) 
        {
            NewDataEventArgs e = new NewDataEventArgs ();
            e.dataReceived += message;
            targetEvent (this,e);
        } 
}
```

Note that ***"ReceiveTask"*** is an extension method I've made to wrap the APM model.

**What I want to approach** is that each time I receive a message from any user that message should be resent to every connected socket (included the one that sent the message)

I've came across with two solutions but I cant't say which one is better.

***First solution: Store workSockets into a Dictionary and make the eventdanler loop through this one while sending the message to the sockets stored in it.***

What I do here is subscribing my AsyncSocketServer class to the event NewData when its constructor is called

```
public AsyncSocketServer ()
{
this.NewData += new EventHandler<NewDataEventArgs> (this.BroadCastMessage);
}
```

Where BroadCastMessage is an asynchronous eventhandler within my AsynSocketServer class.

```
private async void BroadCastMessage(object sender, NewDataEventArgs e)
{

    List<Task<int>> tasks = new List<Task<int>> ();

    byte[] databytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(e.dataReceived);

    lock (lock_AddressBook) 
    {
        foreach (string key in AddressBook.Keys)
        {
            tasks.Add (AddressBook[key].SendTask (databytes));
        }
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

}
```

As you can see this method loops through a maintained Dictionary which contains all the workSockets while performing asynchronous send operations.

***Second solution: Subscribing workSockets to the event***

What I do here is, once a connection is established and before entering the while loop, I create a local eventhandler and attach it to the event.

```
Action<object,NewDataEventArgs> onnewdata = async (sender, e) => 
                {
                    await handler.SendTask (Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(e.dataReceived));
                };

                this.NewData += onnewdata;
```

These are the two solutions I've developed so I'd like to know which one is better, hear about pros and cons or whatever improvement you suggest is welcome.

Comment: IMHO, given the event-based API you've already developed, it's obvious to me that you should have any client that wants notification of a message received by a socket, subscribe to the event for that socket. I.e. your second suggestion. That said, that's merely an opinion and what the best answer in your case is would depend on a lot of details that are missing from your question and which would not be practical to include. The only possible answers here will be inherently "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough. I'm interested about knowing which solution provides more performance/reliability since one solution has an asynchronous eventhandler looping through a dictionary executing tasks and awaiting them all and in the other hand we have a certain number of asynchronous eventhandlers being called in the order they were subscribed.